# Evenly size table columns without setting a width

Tags: html, css

I have a table that will be generated dynamically so I don't know how many columns will be in it. I want all the columns to be the same width, but I cannot set a width because it will depend on the number of columns.

If for example, there are 3 `<th>`s with content, I would like them to be 33% but **without setting a `width` like `33%`**. Also, any content that's inside the div
needs to be `word-wrapped` so that it breaks the word anywhere.

Using my snippet below as an example, the third Column "Bob" doesn't have a the same amount of space as the other 2 columns.

```css
table{
  width: 100%;
}

div{
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

span{
  word-break:break-word;
}
```

```html
<table class="rsHorizontalHeaderTable" style="height:25px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div>
          <div>
            <span id="ctl00_CPH_RadScheduler1_ctl21_ResourceLabel">The Company CEO ( 0 afspraken deze dag )</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div>
          <div>
            <span id="ctl00_CPH_RadScheduler1_ctl23_ResourceLabel">A manager ( 0 afspraken deze dag )</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div>
          <div>
            <span id="ctl00_CPH_RadScheduler1_ctl25_ResourceLabel">Bob </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: If you want 3 columns evenly spaced like 33% each, how come you don't want to set them to 33%?

Comment: because it needs to be dynamical, the amount of columns is based on a `checkboxlist`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `table-layout:fixed`.

If you use this and ***don't set a width for the cells in your first row*** (i.e. your `th`s), then the columns will be divided evenly across the table, no matter how much content they have. The rest of the cells in the columns will also take the width of the first row of columns, no matter what they contain either.

```
table{
    width: 100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
```

Because fixed layout doesn't let you set a min width on the table, we can use a `container` div to do that instead.

Note that I also have moved the border from the `div` (because it can vary in height) to the `th` because it will have the same height across the row.

**Working Example:**

```css
table{
  width: 100%;
  table-layout:fixed;
}
.container{
  min-width:350px;
}

th{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
table div{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

span{
  word-break:break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<table class="rsHorizontalHeaderTable" style="height:25px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div>
          <div>
            <span id="ctl00_CPH_RadScheduler1_ctl21_ResourceLabel">The Company CEO ( 0 afspraken deze dag )</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div>
          <div>
            <span id="ctl00_CPH_RadScheduler1_ctl23_ResourceLabel">A manager ( 0 afspraken deze dag )</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div>
          <div>
            <span id="ctl00_CPH_RadScheduler1_ctl25_ResourceLabel">Bob </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

**Reference**: [Mozilla MDN for table-layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout#Syntax)

Comment: I only used the border for visualisation purposes, otherwise the lines weren't visible in jsfiddle so you didn't have to go through that trouble but +1 for it :P

Comment: @FllnAngl No harm done, it made it look nice for the example anyway! :)

Comment: haha I immediately ran into the next problem, I forgot that I had previously removed `table-layout:fixed;` from the table, because it prevented `min-width:150px` from working. (facepalm).

it's possible to have selected so many employee's that the `table` expands beyond the screen, so I created a scroll for it but the only thing that was acting out were the `th`'s

Comment: @FllnAngl Yeah, it would do that! How about adding the table into a container and put the width limit on *it*? The table will take up the full amount of the container so that should work. I've updated my answer, you should probably update your question too so people who are looking for this will find it also!

Comment: @FllnAngl Just seen your edited comment - If you mean a min-width on each column I don't think there's a way around that, you'll either have to calculate it when you are generating the table or come up with a min-width for the container that will work in most cases :)

Comment: I can't really give a complete example of my situation, but I can tell it's like a schedule, made up of nested tables.
that's why the unevenly aligned columns are possible. simply put, these 3 columns are just the headers of the schedule.

somehow the content of the schedule does evenly align and upholds to the style I set `min-wdith:150px;`

Comment: @FllnAngl OK, that's a big change to your original question. I thought it was just a quick update to the existing question before I saw your edited comment. Adding this to the question changes it a lot and the answers no longer apply. In this case, the Stack Overflow guidelines are to ask the new requirements as a new question instead, so I'm afraid you should undo your edit and post a new question with the new details. Even though its difficult, an example would help too, or even an image of what you need. I'm not really sure from your description exactly what you need :)

Comment: haha I figured you were going to say this :P, I'll see what I can do, because the schedule is like 2000rows of code in HTML

Comment: my god, I can't seem to break it the way it's broken on the live environment.
with the same css

Answer (score 0):

Add table-layout property to your table

```
table-layout: fixed;
```